# Is it possible to use flashloan as liquidity provider?

Tags: ethereumjs, defi, uniswapv3, flash-loans, aave

I am reading about flash loans where I come over a use case of flash loan as providing liquidity to DEXs.

I am bit confused here. How we can earn profits by just providing liquidity to DEXs since we need to hold the deposits for some time to earn the trading fee? We need to repay the flash loan in single transaction so how can we pause the transaction for some time, to accumulate the trading fee, before repaying the falsh loan?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not possible.